# How does sbt filter dependencies

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to add appengine-maven-plugin to my plugin as a compile time dependency.
If I run

```
show update
```

in the sbt console the dependecy is there, but if I run

```
show managedClasspath
```

it is not there anymore and I cannot figure out why.

Here is a minimal build.sbt file which shows this behaviour.

```
sbtPlugin := true

name := "test1"

organization := "com.cornim"

version := "0.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.google.appengine" % "appengine-maven-plugin" % "1.9.51"
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

P.S.: I'm on sbt v0.13.15

Comment: This question was answered on the sbt github page: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3156 - The answer is this is not a bug and to add `classpathTypes += "maven-plugin"`.